# Warning: Missing translation for key: "";

Tags: react-admin

I am using react-admin for creating my website. But i am getting this warning from list page every time '**Warning: Missing translation for key: "";**'

```
const ListTitle = () => {
    return <span>User Agents</span>;
}

 const SitemapFilter = props => (
    <Filter {...props}>
     <TextInput label="Type" source="type" alwaysOn/>
   </Filter>
   );

  export const SitemapList = props => (
     <List {...props} filters={<SitemapFilter />} title={<ListTitle />}>
    <Datagrid>
     <TextField source="type" label="Type"/>
     <UrlField source="url" label="URL"/>
     <EditButton/>
   </Datagrid>
 </List>
);
```

I am not able to find the reason. Please advise.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, after updating the version of React-Admin, I also began to see such a thing, it looks like a bug!

Comment: You can suppress it by adding an empty key to your custom translation files: '': '', ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that `EditButton` component is the cause. Adding label prop to it fixes the issue.

```
<EditButton label="Edit" />
```

Comment: Thanks..This is working for me also. But now Edit button column title has changed as 'Edit'. But I don't need title for that column in listing table. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: You could pass an empty label, like `label=""`. I have filed a bug here: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/3017

Comment: But if I add label as empty (<EditButton label=""/>) then, Edit button text is not showing. Only the icon is there.

Comment: I getting this same warning even after adding the label value (using react-admin v2.9.4).

Answer (score 2):

### tl;dr

Check that your backend returns the proper response!

### Explanation

The [docs on response format](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#response-format) state:

> DELETE: `{ data: {Record|null} }` The record that has been deleted (optional)

In our API the backend returned a simple HTTP 204 without a content (obviously). This caused the error:

> Warning: Missing translation for key: "Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined"

Changing the response to be the deleted record fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are also getting maximum call stack size exceeded with this error you may not be returning a **not null** value from your backend.

For instance, if you have a `<TextField source="type" />` and type is required but you return a null value, then you will get this error.  The solution is to either make it not required or to return a **not null** response.